# SQL Server 2008 - different sort orders on VARCHAR vs NVARCHAR values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, I am seeing some strange behavior when ordering NVARCHAR columns; here are a few quick use cases to demonstrate:

Case 1: ORDER on VARCHAR values:

```
SELECT t.Name
FROM
( 
SELECT CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(500))  As Name
UNION SELECT CAST('-A' AS VARCHAR(500))  AS NAME
) As t
ORDER BY t.Name ASC
```

Which produces (my desired) output of:

-A
A

(The one with the leading dash is displayed first)

Contrast this with the ORDER on NVARCHAR values:

```
SELECT t.Name
FROM
( 
SELECT CAST('A' AS NVARCHAR(500))  As Name
UNION SELECT CAST('-A' AS NVARCHAR(500))  AS NAME
) As t
ORDER BY t.Name ASC
```

Which produces this output:

A
-A

Assuming I want to sort on NVARCHAR fields (I can't change the db design) using a standard ORDER BY clause (I'm using linq2nhib, which prevents me from doing any casting here) - how do I get the sorting to work in the desired fashion (item with the leading non-alphanumeric value displays first)?

I'm hoping there is some sort of database/server-level collation setting for this...any ideas?

Comment: The reason for the behaviour is described here. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322112 I'm not sure if there's a way round it. Would using a binary collation work for you? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/a2785ed0-2355-43f3-bd8b-2200824e9c1f

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that exactly describes the behavior I'm seeing...now I just need a solution! I don't mind changing the collation setting on the db, is there one that will produce my desired results (and still allow for unicode columns, etc)?

Comment: You could use `ORDER BY t.Name  COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN ASC` but this will separate out lower and upper case names. Some more discussion here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/04/07/570397.aspx

Comment: Martin, as mentioned in the question, I can't really have anything special in the order by, as I'm using NHibernate.Linq to perform the queries, all I can expect to get form it is a standard ORDER BY col statement....

Comment: YOu know that just because you are using an ORM for some qwueries doesn't mean you can't get it to execute a sptred proc or queries if you need to write them in abetter, more complex or more performant way than the ORM code that is generated. If a tool doesn't do what you need, then stop using the tool for that.

Answer (score 1):

Either change the collation in the database or change the collation of individual columns in the tables you need consistent ordering on.

The collations `Latin1_General_BIN or Latin1_General_BIN2` work fine with your example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use binary collation to achieve consistent ordering.

```
ORDER BY t.Name ASC COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

**Edit:** 
Since you can't do the collate in the query,
you will need to do it at the database level.

You will need to set it on the column(s) that you are comparing and it needs to be binary.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx)'s an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also order the set with CAST(VARCHAR) on a CTE that returns the primary key and do a join on the table to get the NVARCHAR value.